# Having to reopen ports on reboot

Tags: iptables, firewall

When I restart my computer I keep having reopen ports using iptables. Using a "sudo ufw allow [port]/[protocol]" doesn't open the port and isn't persistent.

Pertinent info
20.04
Was troubleshooting a LAMP stack issue and got that all working but may have apt purged something.

Comment: If you're using `iptables` directly and not `ufw` then you need to make sure your rules are persistent - `iptables-persistent` does this.  If you use ufw you use ufw, if you use iptables you don't use ufw.  Unfortunately, there's not enough information here to really assist you in 'rebuilding' your rules so they work, as is.

Comment: Is it that they are conflicting with eachother? I guess if there are no major dependencies I can just get rid of iptables.

Comment: `ufw` being enabled means you should use `ufw` - it uses `iptables` / `nftables` under the hood depending on what's there.  If you want to use `ufw` then we have to configure it accordingly AND not directly manipulate `iptables` - vice versa if you want to use `iptables` directly, you have to disable and not use `ufw`.  Either way works, but it'll require work to enable properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your firewall is enabled by running `sudo ufw status`.
To enable it run `sudo ufw enable`.

And the command you should run to open a port is `sudo ufw allow [port]/[protocol]`.

Assuming you are running LAMP and want to expose the web server, you would want to run `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp`.

Comment: sudo ufw allow [port]/[protocol] Actually isn’t working

Comment: You're not supposed to type that in the terminal. That's just the syntax. If you want to open the web server, you should do "sudo ufw allow 80/tcp" instead.

80 is the http port.
"tcp" is the network protocol used.
So you would be opening tcp port 80. 

Now I realise I could have explained that better.